# Kendo UI Grid Row Template Command

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having requirement in KendoUI Grid where I have first column as Command template for `checkbox`,so  on its `onclick` event I want to get value and ids  of all the columns of same selected row. below is the column section of my grid

```
columns: [                            
    {command: "", template: '<input type="checkbox" id="check-all" onclick="chkboxclicked(this)"/>', width: "15" },
    { field: "Hours", template: '<input type="textbox" id="txthours" style="width:70px;"/>', width: "30" },
    { field: "OT Hours", template: '<input type="textbox" id="txtOThours"  style="width:70px;"/>', width: "30" },
    { field: "SkillName", title: "Skill", width: "50" },
    { field: "UserName", title: "Technician", width: "65" },
    { field: "StartTimeString", template: '<input type="datetime" id="txtLaborstartdate" style="width:200px;"/>', title: "Start Date time", width: "75" },
    { field: "EndTimeString", template: '<input type="datetime" id="txtLaborEnddate" style="width:200px;"/>', title: "End Date time", width: "75" }
]
```

I have also attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHneL.png) for more detail, please let me know how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Function chkboxclicked(obj){
       var id = $(obj).attr('id');
        var IsChecked = $(obj).is(':checked');
        var rowIndexchild = $(this).parent().index();
        var cellIndexchild = $(this).parent().parent().index();
         var grid = $("#YourGridName").data("kendoGrid");

       var datatItem = grid.dataItem(grid.tbody.find('tr:eq(' + cellIndex + ')'));


      var SkillName= datatItem.SkillName;
      var UserName= datatItem.UserName;
      var StartTimeString= $('#txtLaborstartdate').val();
      var EndTimeString= $('#txtLaborEnddate').val();
      var hours = $('#txthours').val();
      var OThours = $('#txtOThours').val();


}
```

You can find `Hours` value like `$('#txthours').val()`.

Comment: Jaimin
      Getting "Skillname","Username" from Dataitem is fine,that is diretly coming from my service,But I want to Get the Values of "Hours" and "OT Hours" which are Template type Text Boxes and user will enter at run time.

Comment: @AshishShri if i am not wrong than your grid is `editable` right?
and if it's `editable` than first you have to enter value of `hours` & `OT hours`. Than you have to check the `checkbox` and you can get all data.

Comment: Yes,I'm Entering values in Text Boxes and then clicking check box But this is not editable Grid,I want to get all the values of selected row and bind in the parent Read only Grid which will be there in its background,so when i say "Dataitem.Hours" it is showing null value,so i need to get the value of 
  { field: "Hours", template: '<input type="textbox" id="txthours"  />'" }  which will be entered at run time and i'm struggling to get it, Hope  this will clear my quesion now

Comment: @AshishShri right now i am not on my machine.I give you ans as soon as possible.

Comment: @AshishShri I just update my code. Now you can find value of your template `Textbox` like this `$('#txthours').val()`.

Comment: Jaimin,Its working now ,thanks a lot, one more question in my attached screen shot you can see I have 2 date fields(start and End Date) and for only 1st row it is showing date time control,rest all the rows it is showing as simple Text box,I'm using    "$("#txtLaborstartdate").kendoDateTimePicker({                value: new Date()}); ",this code for binding date control on it,how can i bind for all the Start and End date irrespective of rows no.

Comment: @AshishShri i try with your code but it's not working for me ,I think you have to use `rowtemplate`.

Comment: Hi Jaimin,Yes I'm trying with rowtemplate only but still no success,I'm trying with this type of sample code                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
      field: "startDate",
      rowTemplate:kendo.template('<input type="datetime" id="txtLaborstartdate" style="width:200px;"/>')
  }],
  dataSource: [{ startDate: "8/17/2013 3:50 PM" }, { startDate: "8/18/2013 3:50 PM" }]
});

$("#txtLaborstartdate").kendoDateTimePicker({
    value: new Date()
})

Comment: @AshishShri right now i am not on my machine.I give you ans as soon as possible.